# Copy View from Production Replica to Data Warehouse

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, data-warehouse, database-replication

I have a view in my production replica (it's a read-only database) and I need to copy one of the views to my data warehouse.

What would be the best way to go about it?

- I can not create a table from the view on the replica. Meaning I can not do `CREATE TABLE Table_From_View AS SELECT * FROM My_View;`
- I can not copy all the tables that create the view definition. Some of them contain sensitive data.

I am sure I missing something basic here...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, a view doesn't store anything. It's more like an alias or a macro. It just passes the query logic through to underlying base tables.

You need the underlying base tables to exist on the same MySQL instance where you create the view, and the base tables must remain existing on that same MySQL instance while you query the view.

If you only want to copy the contents of a view, so you don't copy the other sensitive data that is not selected by the view, you would have to create a base table to copy the data:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE myview_base AS SELECT * FROM myview;
```

Then you can do a logical dump of that copy table:

```
shell > mysqldump --single-transaction mydatabase myview_base > myview_base.sql
```

Then restore that dump file to your data warehouse as you would any other SQL dump file.

---

Another possible strategy:

```
SELECT * FROM myview INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv';
```

This dumps the result of an SQL query to a file. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

The file will be created on the database server, so if you don't have shell access to the server, you won't be able to retrieve the file.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, this is a read-only DB and I cannot create tables on the source Database